# Why does my rigid body simulation glitch out?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, mesh

I tried to make a rigid body simulation for a chain built out of torus objects. After starting the simulation, the chain links suddenly break apart and go in all sorts of directions for no apparent reason.

[image]

I can't find any solution for this. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: without knowing anything, apply the scale and set the collision type to mesh on all of the pieces.

Comment: That's the problem, i did that already already. All the circles are set to mesh and scale is what it should be.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your rigid body settings panel?

Answer (score 1):

Change the "Shape" (Under Rigidbody Collisions) from "Convex Hull" to "Mesh".

What's happening is that when you use Convex Hull, the simulation can only see a "shrinkwrapped" version of the shape. That is, it won't see the holes, and will therefore think that all the rings have ended up penetrating each other. To resolve this, it will apply a large-ish force to each object to force them apart, resulting in the explosion you see.